# map with incomplete value type

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, std, libc++

I'm getting an error with the following:

```
class Test
{
    std::map<std::string,Test> test;
};
```

The error is "Field has incomplete type 'Test'". I read a few threads with suggested this might be a bug in the version of libcxx which ships with xcode, but it wouldn't surprise me at all if I just have to change it to:

```
class Test
{
    std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Test>> test;
};
```

I just wanted to double check that this is definitely a correct error and not a bug.

Cheers!

Comment: Works for me, gcc 4.6.3 @ ubuntu x64

Comment: The standard requires that all types used in standard containers be complete, so the error is valid. There are, however, implementations of the library that can handle incomplete types as well.

Comment: the `std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr<Test>>` and `std::map<std::string,Test>` are semantically very different! First one stores (smart) pointer, whereas second one the 'whole' object.

Comment: @avakar that explains why the code compiles under VS 2012 but not XCode..

Comment: @Yossarian I realise the implementation will be affected, ie I'll have to allocate the objects with new, but is there anything else I need to watch out for? Thanks =)

Comment: If you do use `shared_ptr` in the manner you suggested, watch out for circular references.

Comment: To begin with, I don't like this definition.it looks like an infinite circular definition to me,but maybe I'm mistaken. what happens if you wrote class Test; before defining your class and use the non shared pointer version of your code_

Comment: @MoatazElmasry I tried that too, but putting in a forward declaration of Test still results in Test being incomplete. Not sure I see where the infinite circular definition comes from? Test instances aren't necessarily going to insert pointers to themselves into the map.

Comment: then just go with pointer as you suggested.but I try personally to be cautious with recursive definitions like yours

Comment: @avakar do you want to submit your comment as an answer? It's exactly the information I was looking for =)

Comment: @Joe : [Boost.Variant](http://www.boost.org/libs/variant/) comes with [`boost::recursive_wrapper<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost/recursive_wrapper.html) to solve _exactly_ this problem. :-]

Comment: Ah, this sucks! I think compiler writers would like to go the extra mile to annoy users, it is perfectly valid to have a type that includes a map that has its type as value. Quite useful too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The standard requires that, all types used in template components of the standard library must be complete, unless otherwise stated. Thus libc++'s error is correct. Using an incomplete type is undefined behavior (§17.6.4.8[res.on.functions]/2), so libstdc++ accepting it isn't wrong either.

You could use a pointer object to construct the complete type as you did. But you could also use some third-party collections library which allows incomplete types, e.g. [`boost::container::map`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost/container/map.html) is [designed to allow incomplete types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/container/containers_of_incomplete_types.html).

---

§17.6.4.8 Other functions / 2:

> In particular, the effects are undefined in the following cases:
>
> - ...
> - if an incomplete type (3.9) is used as a template argument when instantiating a template component, unless specifically allowed for that component.

(The only components that explicitly allow incomplete types are `declval`, `unique_ptr`, `default_delete`, `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` and `enable_shared_from_this`.)

Comment: Note [N4510](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4510.html) (adopted 2015-05) requires `std::vector`, `std::list`, and `std::forward_list` to support incomplete value types. To avoid breaking ABI, not all containers were in the proposal. It is likely that there will be similar requirements on associative containers in future version of C++ (probably after C++17).