# Possible bug in libc++?

Tags: c++, c++11, std, libc++

The following code doesn't compile with clang 3.1, using libc++ (don't know the version, the current one that comes with Xcode). It works fine with other standard libs. Is there an error in my code, or is this a bug in libc++?

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct A {
  A(const map<int, A>& m) {}
};

struct B {
  map<string, A> m;
};
```

The error i'm seeing is in `<utility>`:

```
/usr/lib/c++/v1/utility:241:64: No member named 'value' in 'std::__1::is_nothrow_copy_constructible<A>'
```

I've tried to isolate it further, but this is the minimal example I found. Interestingly, when I replace `string` by `int` in the second map it works (also when I replace `int` by `string` int the first map):

```
map<string, A> m; // Does not work
map<int, A> m; // Works
```

Comment: @hvd the version of Clang that ships with XCode 4.5 identifies itself as `Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)`

Comment: Yuck. Thanks for that. I'll remove my comment, since it doesn't help. I think Apple made a mistake in deviating from the clang version numbers without making it clear that they've done so.

Comment: Am I missing something here or is this just because your `A` is not default-constructible?

Comment: Adding `A() {}` or/and `A(const A&) {}` doesn't make the error go away. As I said, it compiles fine with libstdc++ (or even libc++ from current debian).

Comment: +1 for complete, minimal example. http://SSCCE.ORG

Comment: @ChristianRau Sorry, deleted comment. Mixed default and copy constructible.

Comment: @OlafDietsche It wasn't a response to your comment (which I've never seen), but to the OP using a non-default-constructible type in a standard container (but as he posted, this isn't the cause of the error, anyway).

Comment: If you are interested in a workaround you can attempt to declare the constructor as `template<typename Map = std::map<int, A>> A(Map const& map);`. (I cannot test myself if this will be accepted.)

Comment: More info:  With tip-of-trunk clang (from the svn repository), this example compiles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [map with incomplete value type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281274/map-with-incomplete-value-type)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not exactly an error and I explain you why:

In 1997, shortly before the C++ Standard was completed, the standardization committee received a query: Is it possible to create standard containers with incomplete types? It took a while for the committee to understand the question. What would such a thing even mean, and why on earth would you ever want to do it? The committee eventually worked it out and came up with an answer to the question. (Just so you don't have to skip ahead to the end, the answer is "no.") But the question is much more interesting than the answer: it points to a useful, and insufficiently discussed, programming technique. The standard library doesn't directly support that technique, but the two can be made to coexist.

When you are declaring `const std::map<int, A>&`, `A` is still incomplete and standard does not enforce implementers to provide support for incomplete types, so if you really need it and you have option to use `boost`, you can change your container and use `boost::container` in place of standard container in compilers that don't support this.

Comment: does this imply that `struct B` is not needed in the example?

Comment: Hm, still this doesn't explain some of the behavior. Removing `struct B` makes it work, also changing the type of the key of the map from `int` to `string` makes it compile fine.

Comment: In your code `struct B` is responsible for instantiating `struct A`, removing it, somehow remove `A`, remove `B` and try to instantiate `A` in `main` and see the result by yourself :)

Comment: I see. What about the fact that it works if the two maps are the same?

Comment: Also, I found the source of your first paragraph. It would have helped if you had linked it in your answer ;) http://www.drdobbs.com/the-standard-librarian-containers-of-inc/184403814

Comment: @lucasclemente Sorry I don't get it

Comment: Replace the map in `struct B` by `map<int, A> m;` (`int` instead of `string`), so that the two maps are of the same type. Then it compiles. Why?

Comment: @lucasclemente Sorry I don't know that site, I just use it from my local help of `boost` library. Beside that if you convert `std::map<std::string, A>` to `std::map<int, A>` the problem still exist, your implementation of `std::map` can't handle incomplete types

Comment: @lucasclemente I think that depend on your STL implementation, replace it with something like STLPort and see if it solve the problem

Comment: I see. In C++03 this is even mentioned in the standard in 17.4.3.6. Thanks for your help!