# C++: huge errors using clang to compile a map with iterators as values

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, iterator

I'm trying to use iterators as values in a `std::map` so that I can efficiently lookup an object by either its `id` or iterate it efficiently by its `depth`.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

struct object {
    static int next_id;
    int id;
    int depth;
    std::map<int, object>::iterator id_it;
    std::multimap<int, std::map<int, object>::iterator>::iterator depth_it;
    static std::map<int, object> by_id;
    static std::multimap<int, std::map<int, object>::iterator> by_depth;
    object() = delete;
    object(object const &) = delete;
    object(object &&) = delete;
    object & operator=(object const &) = delete;
    object && operator=(object &&) = delete;
    ~object() = default;
    object(int id) : id(id), depth(rand()) {}
    void init(std::map<int, object>::iterator it) {
        id_it = it;
        depth_it = by_depth.emplace(depth, id_it);
    }
    static int create() {
        auto it = by_id.emplace(next_id, next_id).first;
        it->second.init(it);
        ++next_id;
        return it->second.id;
    }
    static void set_depth(int o, int d) {
        auto it = by_id.find(o);
        if (it == by_id.end())
            return;
        auto & obj = it->second;
        obj.depth = d;
        by_depth.erase(obj.depth_it);
        obj.depth_it = by_depth.emplace(obj.depth, obj.id_it);
    }
    static int get_depth(int o) {
        auto it = by_id.find(o);
        if (it == by_id.end())
            return 0;
        return it->second.depth;
    }
    static int get_id(int o) {
        auto it = by_id.find(o);
        if (it == by_id.end())
            return 0;
        return it->second.id;
    }
    static void destroy(int o) {
        auto it = by_id.find(o);
        if (it == by_id.end())
            return;
        by_depth.erase(it->second.depth_it);
        by_id.erase(it->first);
    }
    template <typename T>
    static void with(T f) {
        for (auto it : by_depth) {
            f(it.second->second.id);
        }
    }
};
int object::next_id = 10000;
std::map<int, object> object::by_id;
std::multimap<int, std::map<int, object>::iterator> object::by_depth;


int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        object::create();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        object::set_depth(rand() % 100 + 10000, rand());
    }
    object::with([](int obj) {
        std::cout << object::get_id(obj) << "->" << object::get_depth(obj) << std::endl;
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        object::destroy(10000 + i);
    }
    object::with([](int obj) {
        std::cout << "Object was not deleted!" << std::endl;
    });
}
```

Clang gives off *huge* errors, but MSVC compiles it fine **in STRICT mode**.

Errors here:

```
In file included from error.cpp:1:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/string:434:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/algorithm:593:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/utility:221:9: error: 
      field has incomplete type 'object'
    _T2 second;
        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:602:16: note: 
      in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::pair<int, object>' requested here
    value_type __value_;
               ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:624:22: note: 
      in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      void *>' requested here
    typedef typename __node::base                                 __node_base;
                     ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:541:19: note: 
      in instantiation of template class 'std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long>' requested here
    _TreeIterator __i_;
                  ^
error.cpp:13:37: note: in instantiation of template class
      'std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long> >' requested here
    std::map<int, object>::iterator id_it;
                                    ^
error.cpp:9:8: note: definition of 'object' is not complete until the closing '}'
struct object {
       ^
In file included from error.cpp:6:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:834:44: error: 
      no viable conversion from 'iterator' (aka '__tree_iterator<value_type, __node_pointer,
      difference_type>') to 'iterator' (aka '__map_iterator<typename __base::iterator>')
          iterator end() _NOEXCEPT {return __tree_.end();}
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
error.cpp:36:25: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::map<int, object,
      std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, object> > >::end'
      requested here
        if (it == by_id.end())
                        ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:539:24: note: 
      candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      'iterator' (aka '__tree_iterator<value_type, __node_pointer, difference_type>') to 'const
      std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long> > &' for 1st argument
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS __map_iterator
                       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:539:24: note: 
      candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      'iterator' (aka '__tree_iterator<value_type, __node_pointer, difference_type>') to
      'std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long> > &&' for 1st argument
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS __map_iterator
                       ^
In file included from error.cpp:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:371:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1968:19: error: 
      static_cast from '__node_pointer' (aka 'std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      void *> *') to '__node_base_pointer' (aka 'std::__1::__tree_node_base<void *> *') is not
      allowed
                  static_cast<__node_base_pointer>(__np));
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1990:5: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__map_value_compare<int, object, std::__1::less<int>, true>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<int, object> > >::erase' requested here
    erase(__i);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:937:25: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::pair<int,
      object>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<int, object, std::__1::less<int>, true>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<int, object> > >::__erase_unique<int>' requested here
        {return __tree_.__erase_unique(__k);}
                        ^
error.cpp:60:15: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::map<int, object,
      std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, object> > >::erase'
      requested here
        by_id.erase(it->first);
              ^
In file included from error.cpp:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:371:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:650:59: error: 
      static_cast from '__node_pointer' (aka 'std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      void *> *') to '__node_base_pointer' (aka 'int') is not allowed
  ...= static_cast<__node_pointer>(__tree_next(static_cast<__node_base_pointer>(__ptr_)));
                                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1961:5: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int,
      object>, std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long>::operator++'
      requested here
    ++__r;
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1990:5: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__map_value_compare<int, object, std::__1::less<int>, true>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<int, object> > >::erase' requested here
    erase(__i);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:937:25: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::pair<int,
      object>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<int, object, std::__1::less<int>, true>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<int, object> > >::__erase_unique<int>' requested here
        {return __tree_.__erase_unique(__k);}
                        ^
error.cpp:60:15: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::map<int, object,
      std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, object> > >::erase'
      requested here
        by_id.erase(it->first);
              ^
In file included from error.cpp:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:371:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:650:19: error: 
      cannot cast from type 'int' to pointer type '__node_pointer' (aka
      'std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *')
  ...= static_cast<__node_pointer>(__tree_next(static_cast<__node_base_pointer>(__ptr_)));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:156:14: error: 
      member reference type 'int' is not a pointer
    if (__x->__right_ != nullptr)
        ~~~  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:650:47: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__tree_next<int>'
      requested here
        {__ptr_ = static_cast<__node_pointer>(__tree_next(static_cast<__node_base_pointe...
                                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1961:5: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int,
      object>, std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long>::operator++'
      requested here
    ++__r;
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1990:5: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__map_value_compare<int, object, std::__1::less<int>, true>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<int, object> > >::erase' requested here
    erase(__i);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:937:25: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::pair<int,
      object>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<int, object, std::__1::less<int>, true>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<int, object> > >::__erase_unique<int>' requested here
        {return __tree_.__erase_unique(__k);}
                        ^
error.cpp:60:15: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::map<int, object,
      std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, object> > >::erase'
      requested here
        by_id.erase(it->first);
              ^
In file included from error.cpp:6:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:371:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:159:20: error: 
      member reference type 'int' is not a pointer
        __x = __x->__parent_;
              ~~~  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:160:17: error: 
      member reference type 'int' is not a pointer
    return __x->__parent_;
           ~~~  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:67:24: error: 
      member reference type 'int' is not a pointer
    return __x == __x->__parent_->__left_;
                  ~~~  ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:158:13: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__tree_is_left_child<int>'
      requested here
    while (!__tree_is_left_child(__x))
            ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:650:47: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__tree_next<int>'
      requested here
        {__ptr_ = static_cast<__node_pointer>(__tree_next(static_cast<__node_base_pointe...
                                              ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1961:5: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int,
      object>, std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long>::operator++'
      requested here
    ++__r;
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/__tree:1990:5: note: 
      in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__map_value_compare<int, object, std::__1::less<int>, true>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<int, object> > >::erase' requested here
    erase(__i);
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:937:25: note: 
      in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::__tree<std::__1::pair<int,
      object>, std::__1::__map_value_compare<int, object, std::__1::less<int>, true>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<int, object> > >::__erase_unique<int>' requested here
        {return __tree_.__erase_unique(__k);}
                        ^
error.cpp:60:15: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::map<int, object,
      std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int, object> > >::erase'
      requested here
        by_id.erase(it->first);
              ^
In file included from error.cpp:6:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:1586:44: error: 
      no viable conversion from 'iterator' (aka '__tree_iterator<value_type, __node_pointer,
      difference_type>') to 'iterator' (aka '__map_iterator<typename __base::iterator>')
          iterator end() _NOEXCEPT {return __tree_.end();}
                                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
error.cpp:64:22: note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::multimap<int,
      std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long> >,
      std::__1::less<int>, std::__1::allocator<std::__1::pair<const int,
      std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long> > > > >::end'
      requested here
        for (auto it : by_depth) {
                     ^
error.cpp:81:5: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'object::with<<lambda
      at error.cpp:81:18> >' requested here
    object::with([](int obj) {
    ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:539:24: note: 
      candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      'iterator' (aka '__tree_iterator<value_type, __node_pointer, difference_type>') to 'const
      std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int,
      std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long> > >,
      std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int,
      std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long> > >, void *> *, long>
      > &' for 1st argument
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS __map_iterator
                       ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/map:539:24: note: 
      candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable: no known conversion from
      'iterator' (aka '__tree_iterator<value_type, __node_pointer, difference_type>') to
      'std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int,
      std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long> > >,
      std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int,
      std::__1::__map_iterator<std::__1::__tree_iterator<std::__1::pair<int, object>,
      std::__1::__tree_node<std::__1::pair<int, object>, void *> *, long> > >, void *> *, long>
      > &&' for 1st argument
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS __map_iterator
                       ^
10 errors generated.
```

Invocation: `g++ -std=c++11 file.cpp` where g++ is clang.

What's going on?

Comment: Welcome to template errors, where programs have been written to make the errors _readable_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the link that Jesse provided, the easiest fix is by using std::unique_ptr, which has the downside of extra heap allocations, but I really see no better option.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

struct object {
    static int next_id;
    int id;
    int depth;
    std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<object>>::iterator id_it;
    std::multimap<int, std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<object>>::iterator>::iterator depth_it;
    static std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<object>> by_id;
    static std::multimap<int, std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<object>>::iterator> by_depth;
    object() = delete;
    object(object const &) = delete;
    object(object &&) = delete;
    object & operator=(object const &) = delete;
    object && operator=(object &&) = delete;
    ~object() = default;
    object(int id) : id(id), depth(rand()) {}
    void init(std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<object>>::iterator it) {
        id_it = it;
        depth_it = by_depth.emplace(depth, id_it);
    }
    static int create() {
        auto it = by_id.emplace(next_id, std::unique_ptr<object>(new object(next_id))).first;
        it->second->init(it);
        ++next_id;
        return it->second->id;
    }
    static void set_depth(int o, int d) {
        auto it = by_id.find(o);
        if (it == by_id.end())
            return;
        auto & obj = it->second;
        obj->depth = d;
        by_depth.erase(obj->depth_it);
        obj->depth_it = by_depth.emplace(obj->depth, obj->id_it);
    }
    static int get_depth(int o) {
        auto it = by_id.find(o);
        if (it == by_id.end())
            return 0;
        return it->second->depth;
    }
    static int get_id(int o) {
        auto it = by_id.find(o);
        if (it == by_id.end())
            return 0;
        return it->second->id;
    }
    static void destroy(int o) {
        auto it = by_id.find(o);
        if (it == by_id.end())
            return;
        by_depth.erase(it->second->depth_it);
        by_id.erase(it->first);
    }
    template <typename T>
    static void with(T f) {
        for (auto it : by_depth) {
            f(it.second->second->id);
        }
    }
};
int object::next_id = 10000;
std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<object>> object::by_id;
std::multimap<int, std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<object>>::iterator> object::by_depth;


int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        object::create();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        object::set_depth(rand() % 100 + 10000, rand());
    }
    object::with([](int obj) {
        std::cout << object::get_id(obj) << "->" << object::get_depth(obj) << std::endl;
    });
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
        object::destroy(10000 + i);
    }
    object::with([](int obj) {
        std::cout << "Object was not deleted!" << std::endl;
    });
}
```

In contrast to what Jesse claims regarding the move constructor and copy constructor, while many containers, such as std::vector, do require MoveConstructible or CopyConstructible, std::map does not.

Answer (score 5):

clang is correct in giving you those errors. I can help explain what they mean:

1) STL container do not allow incomplete types. See [map with incomplete value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281274/map-with-incomplete-value-type).
That is what one of the error messages are trying to tell you: `definition of 'object' is not complete until the closing '}'`.

2) You `delete`d the move constructor **and** the copy constructor:

```
object(object const &) = delete;
object(object &&) = delete;
```

Your use becomes very limited when both are deleted and is why you are getting the following errors: `candidate constructor (the implicit copy constructor) not viable` and `candidate constructor (the implicit move constructor) not viable`.

Comment: Seeing Peters answer below, is it possible to do it without unique_ptr?

Comment: @kvanberendonck: As the link explains, `boost::container` allows incomplete types. Otherwise, `unique_ptr` would be the way to go.