# Why does comparing map iterators need its class defined?

Tags: c++, iterator, visual-studio-2015

See this (simplified) piece of C++ code:

```
#include <map>
class c;
int main(void)
{
  std::map<int, c>::iterator i;
  return i == i;
}
```

Visual Studio 2010 and even 2012 compile this just fine. But when I try it in Visual Studio 2015, I get:

```
1>d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\utility(198): error C2079: 'std::pair::second' uses undefined class 'c'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Kty=int,
1>              _Ty=c
1>          ]
```

I can understand this to a certain extent, but... for comparing iterators (in the end pointers), why does the `class c` have to be defined exactly?

This question is **not** a duplicate of "[map with incomplete value type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281274)": mine is specifically about map *iterators*, not about maps allowing incomplete types (which the Visual C++ version supports just fine!). Nor does Boost's map help me: gives the same error.

I guess all I can do is use pointers instead of iterators...?

I would also be interested to know exactly *which* change in Visual Studio (the `xtree` include file?) caused this.

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 shouldn't compile it as well.

Comment: It is UB to instantiate most standard library containers over an incomplete type. See [res.on.functions]/2.5.

Comment: You're mistakingly assuming that iterators are glorified pointers, although for `std::map` iterators is a reasonably fair assumption. `istream_iterator` is an obvious counter-example.