# Recursive Standard C++ Library Container Types?

Tags: c++, types, containers

Is it possible to define Standard C++ Library Container Types UM, OM and L such that:

- `UM` is an `std::unordered_map` with key_type `int` and mapped_type iterator to `OM`
- `OM` is an `std::map` with key_type `int` and mapped_type `L`
- `L` is an `std::list` of iterators to UM

?

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is no.  You might be able to solve the problem with forward declarations and pointers.

Comment: Thanks @NathanOliver, you are correct wrt forward declaration solution; but to use it, I would need to re-implement these 3 containers and it is quite annoying given iterators for all 3 containers are defined as pointers (in C++ implementation I use anyway); but I cannot use them out of the box because I cannot forward-declare their inner node classes. So just was trying to check if I was missing some obvious solution.

Comment: Could you please disclose what problem are you trying to solve using this data structure?

Comment: @Bob__ just need to manage a collection of many objects with int unique ids that belong to several ordered levels. A level may change; then all its objects should be still attached to the changed level. Need to serve some queries like "find the lowest level greater than x that contains objects from given set", some others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <map>
#include <list>

struct Container{
  struct List;
  using OM = std::map<int, List>;
  using UM = std::unordered_map<int, typename OM::iterator>;
  using L = std::list<typename UM::iterator>;
  struct List{
    L l;
  };
  UM um;
  OM om;
  L l;
};

int main() {
  Container c;
  c.om[0] = Container::List();
  c.um[0]=c.om.begin();
  c.l.push_back(c.um.begin());
}
```

Comment: Do note that this code technically has undefined behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12281274/map-with-incomplete-value-type

Comment: I think in case of std::map a complete node, with value, is not actually instantiated until method is called.